# Is there a shorter name I can use to do a JNDI lookup of an EJB?

Tags: ejb, websphere

I have a Java EE web application (WebSphere 7).  The code looks up EJBs on the app server by doing JDNI look ups.

In my development environment (Eclipse / IBM RAD), the EAR project is called customerEAR, so the JNDI lookup is like this:

```
ejblocal:customerEAR.ear/customerEJB.jar/CustomerService@com.mydomain.service.CustomerServiceLocal
```

But when the EAR is deployed on the production application server, the lookup fails and the log file states that the EJB is available at:

```
ejblocal:server1-dev-customerEAR.ear/customerEJB.jar/CustomerService@com.mydomain.service.CustomerServiceLocal
```

It's possible that the guy deploying the EAR to the server is actually renaming the EAR file from customerEAR.ear to server1-dev-customerEAR.jar -- or maybe WebSphere is renaming stuff on deployment?   I can't get hold of the deployment guy to find out for sure.

But, regardless, my question is:

Is there a cleaner way to do the lookup of the EJBs?  Like, by using a shorter lookup name, or a "relative path" instead of the "full path"?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the deployment guy insists on renaming my EAR before deploying it, I managed to get this to work, I managed to get it working by shortening this:

`ejblocal:customerEAR.ear/customerEJB.jar/CustomerService@com.mydomain.service.CustomerServiceLocal`

to this:

`ejblocal:com.mydomain.service.CustomerServiceLocal`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a name for your remote EJB using annotations in your bean class or define it in ejb-jar.xml.

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "TestBean")
@Remote(TestBeanRemote.class)
public class TestBean implements TestBeanRemote 
{
    //...
}
```

Lookup on client:

```
TestBeanRemote testBeanRemote = (TestBeanRemote)new InitialContext().lookup("TestBean");
```

If you don't use "mappedName" some Application Servers add some suffix to your Bean name to autogenerate a name. So better use "mappedName" to define it server independent.

Comment: thx -- what do you mean 'assuming correct jndi properties are set'? Currently I'm just doing 'new InitialContext().lookup("ejblocal:customerEAR.ear/customerEJB.jar/CustomerService@com.mydomain.service.CustomerServiceLocal")' -- if I change it to '...lookup("CustomerService")' what JNDI properties should I set, and where do I do that? Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Tried it, no it didn't work.  Says "UnavailableException ... CustomerBean: First component in name CustomerBean not found".  I don't have a remote interface, so I didn't include the Remote annotation.  I do have a local interface, though -- is there a Local annotation I should add?

Comment: Can't you just ask the one responsible for the mapped name of the bean? Else you could output all jndi binded names to search for your name manually (google) or check out what the autogenerated name is for the type of server.

Comment: "Can't you just ask the one responsible for the mapped name of the bean?" -- That's me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want shorter names, [create an ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) and specify a binding rather than leaving it to the product to generate an unambiguous one.  See the section entitled "Binding file Example 1".

Depending on whether or not you have multiple EJBs implementing your interface, you can also use "short form" bindings.  See the section entitled "Default binding pattern".